# SQL Server log shipping out of sync error

Tags: sql-server-2008, log-shipping

I have SQL Server 2008 R2, configured for log shipping. But backup, copy, restore are successful. But alert at primary and monitor instance say, out of sync error 14421.

I have schedule of 15 min set for all 3 jobs. and alert set for 3times=45 mins.
but I still get an error,

Please suggest what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend carefully looking through the history for each of the Log Shipping jobs to see if you can find any errors.  I have seen there be errors within the history message even though the overall job shows as having completed successfully.  Hopefully, you'll find some indication as to why it's getting out of sync.

For more information, you can also right-click your SQL Server instance name -> Reports -> Standard Reports -> Transaction Log Shipping Status